# How to create Mintable tokens on Stellar network?

Tags: token

How can I create a concept similar to [Ethereum Mintable token](https://openzeppelin.org/api/docs/token_ERC20_MintableToken.html)s in Stellar Network?

Is this a recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything, that's the default behaviour of assets in Stellar.